# JavaScript functionality to create roles with classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, prototype

I am having a task to implement a functionality to create roles in JS,and each role is defining by its type (Guest, User, Admin).

1. Type **Guest** should have : a method which gets an array of tasks(**constructor**);
   a method which gets tasks id (the array index) and returns a task from the array of tasks(**getTask**)
   **createTask** should not be defined and **changeType** too
2. Type **User** also should have **constructor** like at Guest,also a method **getTask**,and **createTask** -a method which adds a new task to the array of tasks
   **changeType** should not be defined.
3. Type **Admin** should have constructor-a method which gets an array of guests and users;

**getArray**-a method which returns an array of guests and users

**changeType**-a method which gets a number (the array index) modifies the array item at the provided index (changes the object type from a guest to a user and otherwise and as a result, the tasks should migrated from one type to another), and returns a modified array of items

So,i created all classes and methods,but in the final when i test it with npm,i get the messages that :

- Guest should not implement method createTask
- Guest should not implement method changeType
- User should not implement method changeType
- Admin should change type of role from User to Guest

But when i introduce them in console in browser,everything works good,but i observed that  when i write guest.createTask it shows that its undefined and doesnt throw an error,but i think i should get the error.

Here is my code:

```
class Task {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Guest {
    constructor(tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
    getTask(index) {
        return this.tasks[index];
    }
}

class User {
    constructor(tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
    getTask(index) {
        return this.tasks[index];
    }
    createTask(tasks) {
        return this.tasks.push(tasks);
    }
}

class Admin {
    constructor(userGuestArray) {
        this.userGuestArray = userGuestArray;
    }
    getArray() {
        return this.userGuestArray;
    }

    changeType(index, replace, arr) {
        replace = this.userGuestArray;
        arr = this.userGuestArray[index];
        if (replace[index] = Guest) {
            replace[index] = new User(arr.tasks);

        }if (replace[index] = User){
            replace[index] = new Guest(arr.tasks);

        }

        return replace;
    }
}
```

And here is the code to test Guest class:

```
const guest = new Guest(
    [
      new Task('task name 1'),
      new Task('task name 2'),
      new Task('task name 3'),
    ]
  );
expect(guest.getTask(0).name).to.equal('task name 1');
expect(guest.getTask(2).name).to.equal('task name 3');
const guest = new Guest([]);
expect(guest.createTask).to.throw('method \'createTask\' is not defined');
expect(guest.changeType).to.throw('method \'changeType\' is not defined');
```

And below is for admin to change type role:

```
admin = new Admin([
              new Guest([]),
              new Guest([new Task('task name 1')]),
              new User([]),
              new User([new Task('task name 2')]),
        ]);
 it('should change type of role from Guest to User', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[0] instanceof Guest).to.equal(true);
        admin.changeType(0);
        expect(admin.getArray()[0] instanceof User).to.equal(true);
    });

    it('should change type of role from User to Guest', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[3] instanceof User).to.equal(true);
        admin.changeType(3);
        expect(admin.getArray()[3] instanceof Guest).to.equal(true);
        
    });

    it('should move tasks from Guest to User, when change role', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0)).to.deep.equal({ name: 'task name 1'});
        admin.changeType(1);
        expect(admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0)).to.deep.equal({ name: 'task name 1'});
    });
```

Please help to fix the errors,i already burnt my brain.. I tried to make methods private,but i think i dont to it right and doesnt work.I dont know what to do anymore.
PS: i am new to JS and trying to learn with this tasks.

This is the whole test script to understand the assignment :

```
const {Task, Guest, User, Admin} = require('../src');
const chai = require('chai');
const { expect } = chai;

describe('Guest', () => {
  it('should have method getTask', () => {
    const guest = new Guest(
        [
          new Task('task name 1'),
          new Task('task name 2'),
          new Task('task name 3'),
        ]
      );
      console.log(1,guest);
      expect(guest.getTask(0).name).to.equal('task name 1');
      console.log(2,guest.getTask(0).name);
      expect(guest.getTask(2).name).to.equal('task name 3');
      console.log(3,guest.getTask(2).name);
  });

  it('should not implement method createTask', () => {
    const guest = new Guest([]);
    console.log(4,guest);
    expect(guest.createTask).to.throw('method \'createTask\' is not defined');
    console.log(5,guest.createTask);
  });

  it('should not implement method changeType', () => {
    const guest = new Guest([]);
    console.log(6,guest);
    expect(guest.changeType).to.throw('method \'changeType\' is not defined');
    console.log(7,guest.changeType);
  });
});

describe('User', () => {
    let user;
    beforeEach(() => {
        user = new User(
            [
              new Task('task name 1'),
              new Task('task name 2'),
              new Task('task name 3'),
            ]
          );
    })
    console.log(8,user);
    it('should have method getTask', () => {
        expect(9,user.getTask(0).name).to.equal('task name 1');
        console.log(user.getTask(0).name)
        expect(10,user.getTask(2).name).to.equal('task name 3');
    });

    it('should have method createTask', () => {
        expect(user.getTask(0).name).to.equal('task name 1');
        console.log(11,user.getTask(0).name);
        expect(user.getTask(2).name).to.equal('task name 3');
        console.log(12,user.getTask(2).name);
        user.createTask(new Task('task name 4'))
        console.log(13,user.createTask(new Task('task name 4')));
        expect(user.getTask(3).name).to.equal('task name 4');
        console.log(14,user.getTask(3).name);
    });

    it('should not implement method changeType', () => {
        const user = new Guest([]);
        console.log(15,user);
        expect(user.changeType).to.throw('method \'changeType\' is not defined');
        console.log(16,user.changeType);
    });
});

describe('Admin', () => {
    let admin;
    beforeEach(() => {
        admin = new Admin([
              new Guest([]),
              new Guest([new Task('task name 1')]),
              new User([]),
              new User([new Task('task name 2')]),
        ]);
    })
    console.log(17,admin);
    it('should have method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray().length).to.equal(4);
    });
console.log(18,admin.getArray().length);
    it('should return instance of Guest as a first element by the method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[0]).to.deep.equal({ tasks: []});
    });
console.log(19,admin.getArray()[0]);
    it('should return instance of User as a third element by the method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[3]).to.deep.equal({ tasks: [{ name: 'task name 2'}]});
    });
console.log(20,(admin.getArray()[3]));
    it('should return array of roles by the method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()).to.deep.equal([{ tasks: []}, { tasks: [{ name: 'task name 1'}]}, { tasks: []}, { tasks: [{ name: 'task name 2'}]}]);
    });
console.log(21,admin.getArray())
    it('should change type of role from Guest to User', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[0] instanceof Guest).to.equal(true);
        console.log(22,admin.getArray()[0] instanceof Guest);
        admin.changeType(0);
        console.log(23, admin.changeType(0));
        expect(admin.getArray()[0] instanceof User).to.equal(true);
        console.log(24,admin.getArray()[0] instanceof User);
    });

    it('should change type of role from User to Guest', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[3] instanceof User).to.equal(true);
        console.log(25,admin.getArray()[3] instanceof User);
        admin.changeType(3);
        console.log(26,admin.changeType(3));
        expect(admin.getArray()[3] instanceof Guest).to.equal(true);
        console.log(27,admin.getArray()[3] instanceof Guest)
    });

    it('should move tasks from Guest to User, when change role', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0)).to.deep.equal({ name: 'task name 1'});
        console.log(28,admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0));
        admin.changeType(1);
        console.log(29,admin.changeType(1));
        expect(admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0)).to.deep.equal({ name: 'task name 1'});
        console.log(30,admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0));
    });

    
});
```

Dont pay attention to console logs,i tried to debug my code to see where is the error.
Error log :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="Mocha Tests" time="0.0090" tests="13" failures="5">
  <testsuite name="Root Suite" timestamp="2021-11-06T12:36:46" tests="0" time="0.0000" failures="0">
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Guest" timestamp="2021-11-06T12:36:46" tests="3" file="C:\Users\artio\Desktop\6 Classes\8.2.classes\test\index.js" time="0.0040" failures="2">
    <testcase name="Guest should have method getTask" time="0.0010" classname="should have method getTask">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Guest should not implement method createTask" time="0.0010" classname="should not implement method createTask">
      <failure message="expected undefined to be a function" type="AssertionError"><![CDATA[AssertionError: expected undefined to be a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.js:21:38)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)]]></failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Guest should not implement method changeType" time="0.0000" classname="should not implement method changeType">
      <failure message="expected undefined to be a function" type="AssertionError"><![CDATA[AssertionError: expected undefined to be a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.js:26:38)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)]]></failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="User" timestamp="2021-11-06T12:36:46" tests="3" file="C:\Users\artio\Desktop\6 Classes\8.2.classes\test\index.js" time="0.0010" failures="2">
    <testcase name="User should have method getTask" time="0.0000" classname="should have method getTask">
      <failure message="task name 1: expected 9 to equal &apos;task name 1&apos;" type="AssertionError"><![CDATA[AssertionError: task name 1: expected 9 to equal 'task name 1'
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.js:42:43)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)]]></failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="User should have method createTask" time="0.0000" classname="should have method createTask">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="User should not implement method changeType" time="0.0000" classname="should not implement method changeType">
      <failure message="expected undefined to be a function" type="AssertionError"><![CDATA[AssertionError: expected undefined to be a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.js:55:41)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)]]></failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Admin" timestamp="2021-11-06T12:36:46" tests="7" file="C:\Users\artio\Desktop\6 Classes\8.2.classes\test\index.js" time="0.0020" failures="1">
    <testcase name="Admin should have method getArray" time="0.0000" classname="should have method getArray">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Admin should return instance of Guest as a first element by the method getArray" time="0.0000" classname="should return instance of Guest as a first element by the method getArray">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Admin should return instance of User as a third element by the method getArray" time="0.0000" classname="should return instance of User as a third element by the method getArray">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Admin should return array of roles by the method getArray" time="0.0010" classname="should return array of roles by the method getArray">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Admin should change type of role from Guest to User" time="0.0000" classname="should change type of role from Guest to User">
      <failure message="expected false to equal true" type="AssertionError"><![CDATA[AssertionError: expected false to equal true
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.js:84:56)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)]]></failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Admin should change type of role from User to Guest" time="0.0000" classname="should change type of role from User to Guest">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Admin should move tasks from Guest to User, when change role" time="0.0000" classname="should move tasks from Guest to User, when change role">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: Why would you expect `guest.createTask` to throw? The behavior of JS has always been to return `undefined` when you access a property of an object that doesn't exist. You would get an exception if you tried to actually call the method, but you are not doing that

Comment: Yes,this i understand,but i think i should get a Reference error that createTask is undefined or how that error was called. 
"expect(guest.createTask).to.throw('method \'createTask\' is not defined');"

Comment: No, you shouldn't - that is not how JS works. It returns `undefined`, that is how the language standard defines it to be

Comment: But why i get an error at npm test than :(

Comment: @EvilPanda but that expectation doesn't actually correct. There is no such error message. https://i.imgur.com/L3lSLzK.png

Comment: I don't know how your tests look like, so I cannot answer why your `npm test` gives errors

Comment: Test name:
Guest should not implement method createTask
Failure message:
expected [Function: createTask] to throw an error
Failure type:
AssertionError

Comment: *Again*, the error message you expect to be thrown *does not exist*. Therefore the assertion would fail. And I really don't know why you want a code so brittle that relies on specific error messages, instead of testing directly that a given property is not a method (or testing it doesn't exist).

Comment: The problem is that i did the task,but i can not pass the assignment till i get this 4 errors,this is why i should fix them,but i dont know how :\

Comment: If you want to specifically rely on *those* error messages, then you can add the `createTask` method to `Guest` and make it thrown an error that matches the error message assertion. It's the only way to make this code work if you don't want to actually fix it to be correct.

Comment: I added the error log from junit.xml,maybe it will be more clear what i encounter.Maybe i didnt express myself clear,i just should fix the errors i get, to submit the assignment,the thing is that i have just started learning JS,and dont know everything and how they should be correctly implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i managed to do this task,it wasnt hard at all,but it was confusing:

```
class Task {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Guest {
    constructor(tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
    getTask(index) {
        return this.tasks[index];
    }
    createTask() {
        throw new Error("method 'createTask' is not defined");
    }
    changeType() {
        throw new Error("method 'changeType' is not defined");
    }
}

class User {
    constructor(tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
    getTask(index) {
        return this.tasks[index];
    }
    createTask(tasks) {
        return this.tasks.push(tasks);
    }
    changeType() {
        throw new Error("method 'changeType' is not defined");
    }
}

class Admin {
    constructor(userGuestArray) {
        this.userGuestArray = userGuestArray;
    }
    getArray() {
        return this.userGuestArray;
    }

    changeType(index) {
       let mainArray = this.userGuestArray;
       let arr = this.userGuestArray[index];
        if (mainArray[index] instanceof Guest) {
            mainArray[index] = new User(arr.tasks);

        } else if (mainArray[index] instanceof User) {
            mainArray[index] = new Guest(arr.tasks);
        }
        return mainArray;
    }
}
module.exports.Task = Task;
module.exports.Guest = Guest;
module.exports.User = User;
module.exports.Admin = Admin;
```

For the error part i should just throw one,thats why i got errors at test with the message that i should throw an error